# How do I build a CMake project?

Tags: cmake

I have just acquired an arbitrary CMake project from the internet and I am not sure how to compile it. What commands do I need to run to build it from the command line?

Comment: There are roughly a million variants of this question here on SO and I could not find a canonical duplicate. This is my attempt at contributing such a canonical question/answer.

Comment: Agreed, I really like this question because although there are many questions about how to start using CMake many of these questions are not a good example to use as a duplicate for the more general question of how to get started.

Answer (score 22):

### Basic steps

**If you're on a Unix-y operating system**, like Linux or macOS, then you would run:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S /path/to/source-dir -B /path/to/build-dir
$ cmake --build /path/to/build-dir
```

Here, `/path/to/source-dir` is the directory containing the root-level `CMakeLists.txt`, this is most commonly the root of a source control repository. Meanwhile, `/path/to/build-dir` is a *distinct* directory (that does not need to exist yet) that CMake will use to store the generated build system and its outputs. This is called an *out-of-tree* build. You should ***never*** attempt an *in-tree* build with CMake because of the possibility of name clashes and difficulty involved with cleaning up the generated files.

When building with a **single-config** generator (like Make, which is the default on Unix), you specify the build type by setting the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable in the first command, known as the **configure step**. You must **always** set this variable when working with a single-config generator. The built-in configs are `Debug`, `Release`, `RelWithDebInfo`, and `MinSizeRel`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59314670/2137996) for more detail on this.

After the configure step, you may build the project by either calling the underlying build tool (in this case, `make`) or by calling CMake's generic build launcher command (`cmake --build`), as I do here.

**If you're on Windows**, then the default generator is Visual Studio, which is a **multi-config** generator. This means the build type is chosen during the build step rather than the configure step, and the commands must be adjusted accordingly:

```
$ cmake -S /path/to/source-dir -B /path/to/build-dir
$ cmake --build /path/to/build-dir --config Release
```

These steps assume that the CMake build you are looking at is **well behaved**. If a project fails to build with the above steps and you have all of its dependencies installed to system locations (and *they* are well behaved), then you should open an issue with the upstream project. The most common source of bad behavior in mature CMake builds is dependency handling. Too often you will have to read the build or its documentation to determine which variables need to be set (via `-D`, like we did with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` above) for the project to find its dependencies.

### Advanced topics

#### Setting options and cache variables

Some projects offer options to enable/disable tests, components, features, etc. These are typically done by writing entries to the *CMake cache* during the configure step. For example, a common way to disable building tests is to set `BUILD_TESTING` to `NO` at the command line:

```
$ cmake -S /path/to/source-dir -B /path/to/binary-dir [...] -DBUILD_TESTING=NO
```

This particular variable is a *convention*, but is not guaranteed to be honored. Check the project's documentation to see which options are available.

#### Selecting a generator and toolchain

When using the **Visual Studio** generators specifically, you can tell CMake which platform you wish to target and which version of the compiler you would like to use. The full form of the CMake configure command for this is:

```
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A <ARCH> -T<TOOLSET> [...]
```

Valid values of `<ARCH>` include `Win32`, `x64`, `ARM`, and `ARM64`. If `<TOOLSET>` is not specified, then the 32-bit MSVC compiler will be used. Typically, you will want this to be `host=x64` to ensure that 64-bit MSVC is used, which can allocate more memory for large linking steps. You can also set `<TOOLSET>` to `ClangCL` to use the Visual Studio provided ClangCL tools.

On all generators, CMake sniffs the environment for which compiler to use. It checks the `CC` and `CXX` *environment* variables for the C and C++ compilers, respectively. If those are empty, it will look for `cc` and `c++` executables in the `PATH`. You can manually override the compilers by setting the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` *CMake cache* (not environment) variables at the CMake command line (using `-D` again).

#### Installing & using dependencies

Once a CMake project has been built, you may *install* it either systemwide or (preferably) to a local prefix by running:

```
$ cmake --install /path/to/build-dir --prefix /path/to/install-dir [--config Release]
```

Where `--config` is only required if a multi-config generator was used. Once installed to a local prefix, a project that depends on it may be configured by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/path/to/install-dir`.

Comment: This answer is a bit over-complicated. I always just do `cmake <path to source directory>` followed by `make`. On MSys I need to specify the makefile generator, but I do that once, in an alias in my bashrc and then forget about it. The CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is almost never used.

Comment: @AlastairG -- I think you are too focused on your own workflow. First of all, if you aren't using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` with a single-config generator, then you're using the compiler's arbitrary defaults. Maybe that's okay for you, but most people are best served by setting `Release`, `Debug`, etc. You also don't need to create an `alias`; CMake uses the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` env-var when `-G` is missing (you could set that to `MSYS Makefiles`). Also, needing to change directories is annoying to some (me especially), so having the `-S`/`-B` flags and the `cmake --build` runner are nice.

Comment: Also, if you're using Visual Studio or Xcode then you _have_ to worry about the multi-config generator stuff...