# C++/Cmake - Unable to compile MySQL Connector

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector

This is what I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
```

Than I do:

```
cd mysql-connector-cpp
git checkout 8.0
cmake .
```

And than I receive the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- BIG_ENDIAN: 0
Building version 8.0.26
Building on system: Linux-5.11.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Using cmake generator: Unix Makefiles
Using toolset: 
Building 64bit code
Building shared connector library
Configuring CDK as part of MySQL_CONCPP project
-- Looking for SSL library.
CMake Error at cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:79 (message):
  Cannot find appropriate system libraries for SSL.  Make sure you've
  specified a supported SSL version.  Consult the documentation for WITH_SSL
  alternatives
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cdk/cmake/DepFindSSL.cmake:354 (main)
  cdk/cmake/dependency.cmake:42 (include)
  cdk/CMakeLists.txt:96 (find_dependency)


-- Setting up Protobuf.
==== Configuring Protobuf build using cmake generator: Unix Makefiles   -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux;-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=5.11.0-27-generic
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- BIG_ENDIAN: 0
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test protobuf_HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMICS - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/armegon/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf
==== Protobuf build configured.
Processor Count: 8
-- Setting up RapidJSON.
Skipping second declaration of config option: THROW_AS_ASSERT (found in: /home/armegon/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/CMakeLists.txt)
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT
-- Performing Test HAVE_STATIC_ASSERT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME - Failed
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - done
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- ZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT not defined!
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYSTEM_ERROR - Success
-- Check size of wchar_t
-- Check size of wchar_t - done
-- Looking for sys/endian.h
-- Looking for sys/endian.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h
-- Looking for sys/byteorder.h - not found
Wrote configuration header: /home/armegon/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/include/mysql/cdk/config.h
Preparing to merge SHARED library: connector (xapi;devapi)
Connector library name: mysqlcppconn8
Building version 8.0.26
Generating INFO_SRC
Generating INFO_BIN
Install location: /usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-
Connector libraries will be installed at: lib64

Project configuration options:

: BUILD_STATIC: OFF
Build static version of connector library

: WITH_SSL: system
Either 'system' to use system-wide OpenSSL library, or custom OpenSSL location. (default : system)

: WITH_JDBC: OFF
Whether to build a variant of connector library which implements legacy JDBC API

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/armegon/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/armegon/mysql-connector-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The content of `CMakeOutput.log` is [here](https://pastebin.com/fQgHqRi2) and the content of `CMakeError.log` is [here](https://pastebin.com/sSd8n7ha).

Any idea how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I build a CMake project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425557/how-do-i-build-a-cmake-project) -- in particular, `cmake .` -- **never, ever do this**. CMake is meant to be used out-of-source. Try `cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` instead

Comment: @user3389943 how can I install that ?

Comment: You also need to install `libssl-dev` (assuming you're on Ubuntu or similar).

Comment: @AlexReinking: While in-source build is not recommended, its usage is definitely not related to the problem stated in the question post. In the comments you could point to the question containing a good practice, but marking such question as a **duplicate** is wrong: Duplicate questions exposes the **same problem**, not a problem in the same area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never, ever do an in-source build**. `cmake .` is **always** wrong. It *even says so* in the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-cpp.html

This worked for me:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 --branch 8.0 https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -S mysql-connector-cpp -B mysql-connector-cpp-build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ cmake --build mysql-connector-cpp-build
```

---

It also looks like you're missing the SSL dependency. If you're running a Debian derivative (Ubuntu, Mint), you can install this with:

```
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev
```